# Why does $1/\text{series}$ equal $\text{series with changed signs}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Consider the following function and series:

$$ f(z)=-\frac{1}{z} \frac{1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+O(z^4)}{1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+O(z^4)} \tag{1}.$$

I've seen on many posts here and in textbooks that the following can be done:

$$ f(z)=-\frac{1}{z} \left (  1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+O(z^4)  \right) \left (  1+\frac{z^2}{3!}+O(z^4)  \right)\tag{2}$$

**Why can the denominator be brought up with changed signs like that?**

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series $$(1-x)^{-1}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, but how? Can the $-z^2/3!+O(z^4)$ be considered as $x$ and then use "geometric series on a series"?